# Print a DateTime with the same culture format as it was parsed from but with a shorter year component

Tags: c#, datetime

There are [many different ways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country) of representing dates, based on the culture you're using.

Let's say I take the US date for January 2nd, 2018: "1/2/2018".

I want to make a method that returns the same value **in the same culture format** but with only two digits for the year component.

For example:

```
dd/mm/yyyy -> dd/mm/yy
mm/dd/yyyy -> mm/dd/yy
yyyy-mm-dd -> yy-mm-dd
```

I want to take a `DateTime` variable and return the same date variable in the same culture but with the year in the format yy.

Is it ok for every culture if i do something like this?

```
var year = mydate.ToShortDate.ToString("yy");
var date  = mydate.ToShortDate.Substring(0, mydate.Count() - 4) + year;
```

My input will be .ToShortDate() in many cultures

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Your questions is extremely unclear.

Comment: @CDrosos but I think it is hard to differentiate between random changes in the date format like yyyy/mm/dd, dd.mm.yyyy, and so on...

Comment: i have try to explain it. all i want is to to take a date in any format and return it in the same format but with the year in format "yy" and not in "yyyy"

Comment: @Diana there should be a way to do somehow what i want to do.

Comment: What is your input? A `string` or a `DateTime`? If it's a `DateTime`, you can just use a different parameter in `.ToString()`.

Comment: what parameter i can use without changing the culture? the input is DateTime.Now.ToShortDate()

Comment: @CDrosos I made some changes to your post to make it more clear. If I am wrong  please rollback.

Comment: Replace "yyyy" with "yy" in the format string, if it is present of course.

Comment: @BentTranberg my input is .ToShortDate() without a specific format. i want it to work in any culture

Comment: You can't make it work in any culture in a proper way, because there is no rule specifically for year with two digits. So I would just get any long and/or short format string for culture X, then replace "yyyy" with "yy" if it's there, and then use that string on the date. This is a hack, and I doubt very much there is a proper solution.

Comment: http://www.basicdatepicker.com/samples/cultureinfo.aspx

Comment: You will possibly also have to take into account that the long and short formats is something each user can configure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no proper way to do this as far as I know, so the following should be considered a hack.

Let's assume that the date is held in a DateTime. How it got there is not important.

Now the task is to convert it to a string representation according to the short date format, whatever that might be, but with yyyy instead of yy.

http://www.basicdatepicker.com/samples/cultureinfo.aspx

It looks like short date formats contain either yyyy or yy in pretty much all cultures, so let's make that assumption.

The conversion can now be done in this way.

```
var sampleDate = new DateTime(1992, 12, 31);
var formatString = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;
var newFormatString = formatString.Replace("yyyy", "yy");
var sampleDateAsString = sampleDate.ToString(newFormatString);
```

If the original format string does not contain "yyyy", then the new format string will be the same as the original.

Of course you can get the ShortDatePattern for any culture, not only the current culture as shown here.